# How to remove the axis?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

How to remove the black axes?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\newpsstyle{mygrid}
{
        labels=none,
        subticks=5,
        tickcolor=Red,
        subtickcolor=ForestGreen,
        xticksize=-3 3,
        yticksize=-2 2,
        subticksize=1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(2,3)
    \psaxes[style=mygrid](0,0)(-2,-3)(2,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newpsstyle{mygrid}
{
  labels=none,
  subticks=5,
  tickcolor=Red,
  subtickcolor=ForestGreen,
  xticksize=-3 3,
  yticksize=-2 2,
  subticksize=1,
  axesstyle=none,%  <==
}
```

[image]